# Spring Boot: Manage Multiple Endpoint with Rest Template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, endpoint

In my Spring Boot project I have set several endpoints (which refer to some GET or POST REST API) in the application-dev.yml file.

```
spring:
    username: xxx
    password: acb132
    route:
      source:
        protocol: https://
        ip: 10.xxx.y.zz/
        root: "swdfr/"
        paths: >
            - "ofh/ert/hAFG5"
            - "ofh/ert/ryt54"
```

I would like to manage these endpoints within a service class with a single method. Currently I have implemented this solution:

```
//REST CONTROLLER
    @GetMapping("/Multiple_Get")
    public void manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate() throws Exception{
    final String methodName = "manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate()";
        try {
            service.manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.errorLog(methodName, e);
            throw e;
        }   
    }
    
//SERVICE
    @ResponseBody
    public void manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate() {
        final String methodName = "manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate()";
        try {
            String urlGet1 = protocol + ip + root + paths.get(0);
            String urlGet2 = protocol + ip + root + paths.get(1);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate;
                if (urlGet1.startsWith("https") || urlGet2.startsWith("https")) {
                    restTemplate = getRestTemplateForSelfSsl();
                } else {
                    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                }

                // GET1
                ResponseEntity<String> response1 = restTemplate.exchange(urlGet1, HttpMethod.GET, request,
                        String.class);
                HttpStatus statusCode1 = response1.getStatusCode();
                logger.info("STATUS GET1: " + statusCode1);
                
                // GET2
                ResponseEntity<String> response2 = restTemplate.exchange(urlGet2, HttpMethod.GET, request,
                        String.class);
                HttpStatus statusCode2 = response2.getStatusCode();
                logger.info("STATUS GET2: " + statusCode2);
                
            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

public RestTemplate getRestTemplateForSelfSsl()
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

I would like to use a single method making it as generalizable as possible especially if I have to manage a large number of endpoints.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Handling all requests using a central method will not bring simplicity to your code, because sooner or later you'll need to split the logic back into each situation you're going to handle, and, you're going to create a single piece of code that all developers will have to simultaneously have to change, which may be a nightmare to maintain across different code versions. If you want to centralize everything in a single point, check this pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the `paths` and execute the common code, considering you are doing `GET` request for all.

```java
@ResponseBody
public void manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate() {
    final String methodName = "manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate()";
    try {
        paths.forEach(path -> {
            String urlGet = protocol + ip + root + path;
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = urlGet.startsWith("https") ? getRestTemplateForSelfSsl() : new RestTemplate();
                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlGet, HttpMethod.GET, request,
                        String.class);
                HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
                logger.info("STATUS GET - {} : {}", urlGet, statusCode);
            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In case you're gonna use `POST` or any other HTTP methods, mention in `application-dev.yml` file along with the `paths`. Add few extra logic to determine the `HTTP.XXX` before passing into `restTemplate.exchange()`.

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution with only GET HTTP methods, but I don't seee any logs about statusCode...why??

Comment: Updated the answer, please give it a try.
Change the logger method to `logger.info("STATUS GET - " + urlGet + " : " + statusCode);` in case the `{}` placeholders are not working, and check once.

Comment: I tried but I still don't see any logs ... I had to change the catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) to catch (HttpStatusCodeException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) because otherwise STS would not make me compile the code ... When I run the application when I try to execute the method this enters the try but exits immediately

Comment: Created a sample app with minimum viable code [here](https://codeshare.io/oQQ07o). Omitted `getRestTemplateForSelfSsl()` usage, hardcoded the URLs and simply used `RestTemplate`. It is showing logs as expected. Please debug your code and verify if the internal methods are working fine, and the properties are read properly. In case the endpoints cannot be reached at least it should show an error log like this `I/O error on GET request for https://petstore.swagger.ion/v2/pet/findByStatus`

Comment: I tried omitting the getRestTemplateForSelfSsl () method, but I get "PKIX path building failed". The getRestTemplateForSelfSsl method is used to trust the ssl certificate. I posted the getRestTemplateForSelfSsl () method in my initial post. Can you fit it?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. If you don't mind could you please raise a new question for `getRestTemplateForSelfSsl()`, since the issue is with this method? And since the question was about to generalize `manageGetEndpointsWithRestTemplate()` method only, can you please mark my answer correct.
I will look into the SSL issue and get back to you :)